# ko.observableArray() not adding elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying out KO but have problems getting observableArray to work, the code is very simple

```
​var test = new ko.observableArray();
var regulararray = [];

test.push("item");
regulararray.push("regularpush");
console.log("the length for ko: " + test.length + " the length for regular array: " +    regulararray.length);​​
```

For some reason the length of the knockout array is 0 while the regular array length is 1.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `test().length` instead of `test.length`

Comment: Thanks a million, i struggled with this for two hours without getting anywhere :)